# Dataset not migrating in Visual Studio 2022 from .Net Framework 4.6.1 to .NetFramework 4.7.2

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a Windows Forms project in Visual Studio 2022 containing a dataset that builds OK when I target .Net Framework 4.6.1 but throws a number of errors including "type or namespace not found", "No definition for Update" for one of the tables defined in the dataset if I try and target .Net Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: There's really not enough here for anyone to help you. How did you “target .Net Framework 4.7.2”? Compare the current version to the previous version in your source control or Visual Studio.

Comment: .Net Framework 4.7.2 is selected in the project Application data as Target Framework. In the 4.6.1 version dataset1.xsd is shown in solution explorer with an icon of 2 offset blue cylinders. in the 4.7.2 version the icon is not the same as in the 4.6.1 version but the files are identical.

Comment: The icon for dataset1.xsd in the 4.7.2 is for an XML schema, not a dataset. Adding a dataset via the Add->New Item option shows the added file (dataset2.xsd) with the same 2- cylinder icon  as appear for dataset1.xsd in the 4.6.1 version. Somehow dataset1.xsd is being interpreted as an XML schema in 4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by deleting DataSet1.xsd from the 4.7.2 solution, adding a new dataset object called DataSet1, closing the solution and then replacing the files DataSet1.xsd, DataSet1.cs, DataSet1.Designer,cs, DataSet1.xsc and DataSet1.xss with corresponding files from the 4.6.1 solution. DataSet1.xsd now shows the dataset icon rather than the XML Schema icon in Solution Explorer and the project builds OK.